# Compare lists of floats with decreased precision

Tags: floating-point, common-lisp, precision, floating-accuracy

I am writing the test for a function that does heavy float numbers computations. Naturally when calculating floats you don't expect to get perfectly accurate results. However this is a problem for my tests as I need to compare the expected results with the actual results produced by the function.

The result of my function is an alist of floats. For example:

```
(is (my-function "arg1" "arg2")
    '((0 1.0)
      (1 2.0)))
```

Will produce:

```
((0 1.00000014) (1 2.1)) is expected to be ((0 1) (1 2.1))
```

My question is: **How can I traverse the alist and compare each number with decreased precision?**

[`prove`](https://github.com/fukamachi/prove) allows me to specify a test function when comparing the expected and actual results. Here is my code so far:

```
(defun compare-floats (f1 f2)
  (= (round-to f1 6)
     (round-to f2 6)))

(defun round-to (number &optional (precision 6))
  (let ((div (expt 10 precision)))
    (/ (round (* number div)) div)))

(is (my-function "arg1" "arg2")
    '((0 1.0)
      (1 2.0))
     :test #'(lambda (expected actual)
               (every #'identity
                      (mapcar #'(lambda (list1 list2)
                                  (compare-floats (second list1)
                                                  (second list2)))
                              expected
                              actual))))
```

This works but it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that:

```
(every #'identity
       (mapcar #'(lambda (list1 list2)
                   (compare-floats (second list1)
                                   (second list2)))
               expected
               actual))
```

... can be written:

```
(every (lambda (list1 list2)
         (compare-floats (second list1) (second list2)))
       actual
       expected)
```

Note that `every` will stop comparing numbers as soon as one test returns NIL, which is not the case in your original function. If you performed important side-effects, this would be different.

As for testing floats, I would have used something like this:

```
(defun floats-rougly-equal-p (f1 f2 &optional (precision 1e-6))
  (< (abs (- f1 f2)) precision))
```

But if your code works, don't try to spend too much time finding the most elegant approach.

Comment: Thanks! Much nicer indeed. :) I am "spending time" because I am trying to become better at programming :) Of course one can say that a good developer knows when to move on...

Comment: @tsikov I understand. It was just a warning: `(declare (optimize (elegance 3)))` is not standardized.

Answer (score 2):

**LOOP**:

```
(loop for (nil a) in actual
      and (nil b) in expected
      always (compare-floats a b))
```

Note btw. that Common Lisp also provides double floats...